# Hbase scan with offset

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

Is there a way to scan a HBase table getting, for example, the first 100
results, then later get the next 100 and so on... Just like in SQL we do
with LIMIT and OFFSET?
My row keys are uuid

Answer (score 5):

You can do it multiple ways. The easiest one is a page filter. Below is the code example from *[HBase: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920014348.do)*, page 150.

```
private static final byte[] POSTFIX = new byte[] { 0x00 };
Filter filter = new PageFilter(15);
int totalRows = 0; byte[] lastRow = null; 
while (true) {
  Scan scan = new Scan(); 
  scan.setFilter(filter); 
  if (lastRow != null) {
    byte[] startRow = Bytes.add(lastRow, POSTFIX); 
    System.out.println("start row: " + Bytes.toStringBinary(startRow)); 
    scan.setStartRow(startRow);
  } 
  ResultScanner scanner = table.getScanner(scan); 
  int localRows = 0;
     Result result;
     while ((result = scanner.next()) != null) {
     System.out.println(localRows++ + ": " + result); 
     totalRows++; 
     lastRow = result.getRow();
  } 
  scanner.close(); 
  if (localRows == 0) break;
}

 System.out.println("total rows: " + totalRows);
```

Or you can set catching on scan for the limit you want and then change the start row to the last row + 1 from the prev scan for every get.

Comment: I saw it in hbase the definitive.It has a big over head.

Comment: I am not sure about the big overhead here. This is the same as scan with a cache. You find the start row (easy) and start reading it till the limit is reached. the only minor issue is mentioned in definitive guide as " Filters run on different region servers in parallel and cannot retain or communicate their current state across those boundaries. Thus, each filter is required to scan at least up to pageCount rows before ending the scan. This means a slight inefficiency is given for the PageFilter as more rows are reported to the client than necessary."

Comment: Hi Arun, is there a way to let a user select the `ith` page? With your approach, I am able to permit the user to iterate over the entire result set, 1 "page" at a time, but I am not able to let the user chose any given page number that he wants to go to.

Comment: I'd prefer a `do {} while(localRows != 0)` rather than a `while(true) { break}`. Otherwise, awesome. thank you